# iOs application crash on install

Tags: iphone, xcode, ios5

I am developing an iPhone application and trying to publish the application via a website. This should work for devices that are registered with the provision profile and it does work when deploying from XCode. Using the site (with a link to a .plist file) the device downloads the application, starts installing but once it is finished the application disappears. I checked the console and the following is shown during installation

```
Jan 16 10:47:00 unknown SpringBoard[15] <Warning>: could not save thumbnail for downloading icon: image=(null) path='/var/mobile/Library/SpringBoard/DownloadingIconImageCache/MyApp-0B277314-1342-4C88-B4D0-E763EAC12E3B'

Jan 16 10:47:00 unknown SpringBoard[15] <Warning>: could not save thumbnail for downloading icon: image=(null) path='/var/mobile/Library/SpringBoard/DownloadingIconImageCache/MyApp-C35ECE7C-D138-48B7-9195-71E66CED4636'
```

The problem only occurs on devices with iOs 5. What could be the problem and what should I check?

Thanks
Martijn

Comment: if it's for testing purposes, I'd recommend looking at TestFlight to distribute your app

Comment: Turned out i had an invalid plist file. Funny thing is that the application did install on iOs. Hope this is of use to someone

Comment: Nice one. A good idea is to answer the question yourself below then mark it answered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turned out i had an invalid plist file. Funny thing is that the application did install on iOS 4. Hope this is of use to someone.

Comment: Actually running into this problem as well presently.  What exactly was invalid in your plist?  Also... are you referring to the info.plist or some other plist file?

Answer (score 4):

I had the same issue because I changed the app identifier to build with new certificates. As the log message said "Could not save thumbnail", the problem was with graphics/icons. From build settings, I modified "Compress PNG file" for release version as "NO", which made XCode to include graphics again, and it resolved the issue.

Other suggestions like changing the plist file name, or cleaning build folder didn't work for me. My 2 cents.

Comment: Under "packaging" tab

Answer (score 0):

I've just had exactly the same problem with the same error on the console during sync, but for a different reason.

My app installed fine on iOS4.x devices (iPhone 3Gs and iPod Touch) but failed on my 5.x device (iPad2). I couldn't find anything wrong with the info.plist.

In the end, after several hours of head scratching, I deleted the app from the iTunes library on my PC and re-added it. It now installs okay on all of my devices again.

Answer (score 0):

The problem might be that the bundle-identifier in the deployment plist file does not match the bundle-identifier in the Info.plist.
I had the same issue, the icon disappeared after installation finished, and it turned out that we were reusing an old plist for ad-hoc deployment even after we had to change the bundle identifier for App Store release.