# IOS MDM Server IOS App OTA Deployment

Tags: ios, mdm

We've built an MDM server using a mac mini.
We have 2 applications to push out to a number of users.  One app will push and download on the remote devices with out a problem.  The other displays an error "The app could not be installed at this time"

This second application is an older application.. however we are building it for 6.0.  In the console we see this.

```
ipad SpringBoard[65] <Warning>: could not save thumbnail for downloading icon: image=(null) path='/var/mobile/Library/SpringBoard/DownloadingIconImageCache/
```

This app can be built an installed when a device is connected to the build computer.  We have all of the signing the same as the first application.  We can also archive the app without any errors.  What would cause this app to not install, or what should we start with?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok this took days to figure this out... In my situation at some point another icon was added into the build settings.  We did change the name of the bundle so I'm assuming that xcode automatically populates the icon information?

In the info tab check to make sure you only have one property for 'icon files' (to be clear you should have the ability to open the drop down menu and expose sub menus... What I had was 2 'icon file' sections.)  After I deleted the second set of icon files it pushed fine.

Hope that helps others figure out a very frustrating situation

Answer (score 0):

Several notes/ideas:

a) Take a look at this (they mention the same problem)

[Trouble installing AD-HOC distribution through safari](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9354936/trouble-installing-ad-hoc-distribution-through-safari)

[iOs application crash on install](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8878216/ios-application-crash-on-install)

[Ad-hoc distribution fail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13495469/ad-hoc-distribution-fail)

http://community.phonegap.com/nitobi/topics/not_installing_my_application_in_ipod

b) Can you please post your manifest (if you are installing inhouse apps)?

Please double check that that if you pointing to icons in this manifest, the links are correct.

Comment: Thank you Victor
Yes both of the apps are in house apps.  As far as the plist is concerned I'm not sure I can post exactly the one we are using?  The reason is when we save the .ipa file xcode will create the manafest for you.  However we are using a mac mini with OS X server with profile manager to deploy and manage devices.  

Profile manager creates it's own plist when you upload the .ipa file.. the xcode created one is not used.  I was wondering if there may be an issue there but I'm not sure I can access the file

Comment: I also just looked through each of the links (Thank you) but I've already verified all of the settings and links, I've even compared them to the settings in the app that did work but still doesnt lead me anywhere.... The only difference between my situation and the referenced links is that we are using profile manager so it hosts the app for us and creates it's own plist when the ipa is uploaded..  The app that does not work was built to deploy to 4.2 we changed it to 6.0 I was wondering if there was something that may have been missed there?

Comment: @Monergy: I don' think that changing 4.2 to 6.0 should have changed anything. Sorry, I am out of ideas here. DId you try to deliver any other app?

Comment: Thanks Victor... I finally figured it out yesterday.. see below for the answer.  Thank you for your help!